# How to reflect database objects using Pony ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, database, orm, ponyorm

I have an existing MySQL database that I want to reflect using [PonyORM](http://ponyorm.com/).

I know I'm able to do that with *SQLAlchemy*:

```
engine = create_engine(...)
Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(bind=engine))
...
...
class MyTable(Base):
    __table__ = Table('table_name', Base.metadata, autoload=True)
```

Is there a similiar way to do the same with PonyORM? I couldn't find information about that in the website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently PonyORM does not have something like `autoload=true`, so entities have to be declared in Python. We can add support of database reflection in the future.

Comment: Thank you.  Would be great if we'll have this feature.

Comment: Has this changed any in the last two years?

Comment: The original answer was given on Jul 12 of THIS year, not on 2012 ;) Nothing changed, our current priorities are Python 3 and migrations. Auto-reflection probably will not be implemented soon, because legacy database layouts can be really weird, and it is not easy to write algorithm which auto-generate nice entities from weird schemas.

Comment: 2 years later (2016) a google search for "pony orm use existing sql schema" points to this page. Has anything changed?

Comment: At this moment Pony still does not support reflexion from the database. Right now we are working on migrations, and after that we can add reflexion capabilities.

Comment: What about in 2020 ?